# Unable to send HTTP data from a Rust program

Tags: node.js, rust

I want to connect my Rust client to my NodeJS server. The problem is that my server doesn't seem to detect the data sent correctly.

Here's my rust client:

```
use reqwest::Client;

const REQUEST_URL: &str = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/register";

pub async fn register(hwid: &str) -> u8 {
    let client = Client::new();
    println!("Sending HWID: {}", hwid);
    loop {
        let response = match client.post(REQUEST_URL)
        .body(hwid.to_string())
        .send()
        .await {
            Ok(res) => res,
            Err(_) => {
                continue;
            }
        };
        if response.status().is_success() {
            match response.text().await {
                Ok(ex_code) => {
                    match ex_code.parse::<u8>() {
                        Ok(ret) => {
                            return ret;
                        },
                        Err(_) => {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                },
                Err(_) => {
                    continue;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what the client shows me:

`Sending HWID: 376b85d612e136414a6b3636c6b0201ca5f6db2ec31366afea9481640fa6564e9b912123affad799682931015e3faa878c36bf3fc2d87bde57f8e546d367a20a`

Here is my server-side code:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import clc from 'cli-color';
import { initBot } from './telegram/bot';
import { connect } from './database/connection';
import { createClient, getStatus } from './database/client_handler';

const server = express();
const port = process.env.SEVRER_PORT;

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

server.post('/register', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const hwid: string = req.body.hwid;
    const ip: string = req.ip ?? "Unknown";
    if (!hwid) {
        console.error(clc.red(`[!] HWID not found.`));
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Please give HWID.' });
    }
    let exCode: number = 1;

    if (await getStatus(hwid) == 0) {
        if (await createClient(hwid, ip) == 0) {
            exCode = 0;
        }
    } else {
        exCode = 1;
    }

    res.json({ exCode: exCode });
});

server.listen(port, async () => {
    await connect();
    initBot();
    console.info(clc.cyanBright(`[i] Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`));
});
```

The server keeps telling me: `[!] HWID not found.`

I therefore conclude that I'm filling in my request incorrectly on the client side, but I don't know what else to do.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: There is no `hwid` field in the body you send, so the server should probably use `const hwid: String = req.body;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work properly we need to add a few things:

1. Add bodyParser.text middleware that will parse the text (using utf-8 encoding) and assign it to `req.body`. However, do read [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) and note that it only does that when the right Content-Type header is passed.

```js
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```

2. Now you can assign body directly to the variable you are creating `const hwid: String = req.body;`
3. Now your server can parse text, but Rust client is not sending right Content-Type header. The bodyParser.text middleware by default is expecting `text/plain` value. Include it in your reqwest:

```rust
let response = match client.post(REQUEST_URL)
.header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
.body(hwid.to_string())
```

4. The server is currently responding with a JSON while Rust code expects a text. You can change the response to text using `res.send(exCode);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The server receives and processes the `hwid` correctly, but the client does not seem to receive the reply (the `u8`) and loops continuously.

Comment: @فِرجِيل the client does receive the reply, but the client expects a plain number (e.g. `123`) but the server sends a JSON (e.g. `{ exCode: 123 }` → you need to parse the JSON properly or have the server send a plain number. BTW don't ignore errors completely, at least trace them before you `continue;`, that way you can see yourself where the problem lies.

Comment: @فِرجِيل as Jmb suggested you can send a plain text. I've updated the answer with a solution for this.

Comment: @Jmb @pr0gramista Thanks, it worked with `res.send(exCode.toString());`